# Getting a 'Range' of object '_Global' failed (Run-Time Error 1004) when running an Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

These are the steps of the macro:

1. This macro is supposed to select A1 and enter it as a blank space to reiterate the random variables in the excel sheet.
2. Select the output from the random inputs and copy it.
3. Select a place to output the copied date, in this case "Row 200, Column(n)" and then paste each set of results in a new column as n iterates.

I'm getting a 1004 range error, and I'm not sure how to fix it. What am I missing?

```
Sub newloop()
'
' newloop Macro
'

Dim n As Integer

n = 1
Do Until n = 5
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
Range("AA25,AA47,AA69,AA91,AA113,AA135,AA157,AA179,AA201,AA223,AA245,AA267,AA289").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("R200C" & n).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
n = n + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I believe it's the `.Copy` line. You can't copy non-contiguous ranges.

Comment: @BruceWayne You can! That part works fine, the VBA debugger in excel is pointing to `Range("R200C" & n).Select` as the issue.

Comment: `Range("R200C" & n).Select` what range is that supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

other than fixing the range syntax error, you can avoid changing A1 cell at every iteration since sheet calculation would be triggered at every copy/paste operation:

```
Sub newloop()
    Dim n As Integer

    Range("A1").Value = "" ' trigger first sheet calculation
    With Range("AA25,AA47,AA69,AA91,AA113,AA135,AA157,AA179,AA201,AA223,AA245,AA267,AA289") ' reference input range
        For n = 1 To 5
            .Copy Cells(200, n) ' copy referenced range and paste it to current nth column from row 200 downwards
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

even better, have sheet calculate directly by means of `Calculate` method:

```
Sub newloop()
    Dim n As Integer

    ActiveSheet.Calculate
    With Range("AA25,AA47,AA69,AA91,AA113,AA135,AA157,AA179,AA201,AA223,AA245,AA267,AA289")
        For n = 1 To 5
            .Copy Cells(200, n)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

The **R1C1** notation is not supported in `Range()` as a parameter. Thus, change:

`Range("R200C" & n).Select`

with:

`Cells(200,n).Select`

and the error would dissappear.

Answer (score 0):

## The Solution

It is a good habit to use constants at the beginning of the code, so you can
quickly change something and observe the behavior of the code e.g. you want to paste the data into the 500th row or you want 10 times the results instead of 5, or you want to add another cell range...

```
Sub NewLoop()

  Const cStrRange As String = "AA25,AA47,AA69,AA91,AA113,AA135,AA157," & _
                              "AA179,AA201,AA223,AA245,AA267,AA289"
  Const cLngRow As Long = 200
  Const cN As Integer = 5

  Dim oRng As Range
  Dim n As Integer

  Set oRng = Range(cStrRange)

  For n = 1 To cN
    Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = ""
    oRng.Copy Cells(cLngRow, n)
  Next

End Sub
```

---

## Missing the Point

**When you don't read the OP's wishes carefully:**

### Exemplary, Short and Shorter

```
Option Explicit

Sub NewLoopExemplary()

  Const cStrA As String = "A1"
  Const cStrRange As String = "AA25,AA47,AA69,AA91,AA113,AA135,AA157," & _
                              "AA179,AA201,AA223,AA245,AA267,AA289"
  Const cLngRow As Long = 200
  Const cN As Integer = 5

  Dim oRng As Range

  Range(cStrA).FormulaR1C1 = ""
  Set oRng = Range(cStrRange)
  oRng.Copy Cells(cLngRow, 1).Resize(1, cN)

End Sub

Sub NewLoopShort()
  Const n As Integer = 5
  Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = ""
  Range("AA25,AA47,AA69,AA91,AA113,AA135,AA157,AA179,AA201,AA223,AA245,AA267," _
      & "AA289").Copy Cells(200, 1).Resize(1, n)
End Sub

Sub NewLoopShorter()
  Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = ""
  Range("AA25,AA47,AA69,AA91,AA113,AA135,AA157,AA179,AA201,AA223,AA245,AA267," _
      & "AA289").Copy Cells(200, 1).Resize(1, 5)
End Sub
```